# Insert Multiple Array in Array to Store in Cart CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, frameworks

I have array from foreach loop like this :

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 2 
    [qty] => 1 
    [price] => 130000 
    [name] => 0002/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 
) 
Array ( 
    [id] => 3 
    [qty] => 1 
    [price] => 120000 
    [name] => 0003/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 
) 
Array ( 
    [id] => 4 
    [qty] => 1 
    [price] => 150000 
    [name] => 0004/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 
)
```

I want insert data array in array like this :

```
Array( 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [qty] => 1 
        [price] => 130000 
        [name] => 0002/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 
    ), 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [qty] => 1 
        [price] => 120000 
        [name] => 0003/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 
    ), 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 4 
        [qty] => 1 
        [price] => 150000 
        [name] => 0004/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 
    )
);
```

I try and code like this :

```
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST['id_kuitansi'] as $id_kuitansi){
    $detail_kuitansi = $this->kuitansi_model->detail($id_kuitansi);
    $i = $this->input;
    $data = array(
      'id' => $id_kuitansi,
      'qty' => '1',
      'price' => $detail_kuitansi['nilai'],
      'name' => $detail_kuitansi['no_kuitansi']
    );
    print_r($data);
    //$this->cart->insert($data);
}
```

Comment: Use `$data[] = array (...` instead of `$data = array(...` in loop

Comment: Sorry, i want result like this : I want insert data array in array like this (has been edited in accordance with the desired results) :

 Array( 
  Array ( 
   'id' => 2,
   'qty' => 1,
   'price' => 130000,
   'name' => 0002/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 
  ), 
  Array ( 
   'id' => 3,
   'qty' => 1,
   'price' => 120000,
   'name' => 0003/PNBP/411971/1/02/18
  ), 
  Array ( 
   'id' => 4,
   'qty' => 1,
   'price' => 150000,
   'name' => 0004/PNBP/411971/1/02/18
  )
 );

Comment: Result use $data[] --> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [qty] => 1 [price] => 130000 [name] => 0002/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [qty] => 1 [price] => 130000 [name] => 0002/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [qty] => 1 [price] => 120000 [name] => 0003/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [qty] => 1 [price] => 130000 [name] => 0002/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [qty] => 1 [price] => 120000 [name] => 0003/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [qty] => 1 [price] => 150000 [name] => 0004/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 ) )

Comment: Print `$data` out of loop

Comment: Thanks mohammad. After modified, data result like it : Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => '2', [qty] => '1', [price] => 130000, [name] => '0002/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => '3', [qty] => '1', [price] => 120000, [name] => '0003/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => '4', [qty] => '1', [price] => 150000, [name] => '0004/PNBP/411971/1/02/18 ) )

Comment: How to remove key before Array : [0] [1] [2] before => Array

Comment: you can't, an array always has a key, if it isn't explicitly defined it is numerical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST['id_kuitansi'] as $id_kuitansi){
    $detail_kuitansi = $this->kuitansi_model->detail($id_kuitansi);
    $i = $this->input;
    $data[] .= array( 
      'id' => $id_kuitansi,
      'qty' => '1',
      'price' => $detail_kuitansi['nilai'],
      'name' => $detail_kuitansi['no_kuitansi']
    );
    print_r($data);
    //$this->cart->insert($data);
}
```

You were simply reassigned the values to $data each while you need to append the array value to the $data array

Comment: Thanks RopAli, its not work, but my problem was solved. xD

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved with this code :**

```
foreach ($_POST['id_kuitansi'] as $id_kuitansi)
{
    $detail_kuitansi = $this->kuitansi_model->detail($id_kuitansi);
    $i = $this->input;
    $data[] = array(
      'id' => $id_kuitansi,
      'qty' => '1',
      'price' => $detail_kuitansi['nilai'],
      'name' => $detail_kuitansi['no_kuitansi']
    );
}
//print_r($data);
$this->cart->insert($data);
```

Thanks Mohammad...

Answer (score 0):

whenever we need to insert multiple data in single query, then we can user batch for inserting data. such as,

```
$data = $arrInsert = array();
foreach ($_POST['id_kuitansi'] as $id_kuitansi){
    $detail_kuitansi = $this->kuitansi_model->detail($id_kuitansi);
    $i = $this->input;
    $data = array(
      'id' => $id_kuitansi,
      'qty' => '1',
      'price' => $detail_kuitansi['nilai'],
      'name' => $detail_kuitansi['no_kuitansi']
    );
    //print_r($data);
    $arrInsert[] = $data;
    //$this->cart->insert($data);
}
$this->db->insert_batch('tableName', $arrInsert);
```

In insert batch you can replace tableName with your table name.